# Navigate through the submenu using up and down arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Navigate through the sub menu using up and down arrow after opening the main menu using <kbd>Tab</kbd> and navigate back to main menu using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I have tried the following jQuery:

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) {
  if ($('li').is(':focus')) {
    $("li:focus").next().focus();
  }
```

The result is the focus from the main menu is passing to the submenu by pressing the down key but the submenu is closing suddenly.

This is the [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/davemcg3/pen/eMQYLa?editors=1111).

Comment: Where have you tried that jQuery? I don’t see that anywhere in your code. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Where is your handle keyCode? I didn't see it in the codepen

Comment: it is not there in the code pen
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
          if ($('li').is(':focus')) {  $("li:focus").next().focus();
          } else {$("li:first-child").focus();}
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
          if ($('li').is(':focus')) {
            $("li:focus").prev().focus();
          } else {
            $("li:first-child").focus();
}} else if (e.keyCode == 9 && e.shiftKey) {
          if ($('li').is(':focus')) {            $("li:focus").prev().focus();
          } else {$("li:first-child").focus();   }} pasted this code under script tag